# mysql load data infile it contain more data than there were input column

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm a new to mysql, I try load csv file to mysql.
the csv like:

```
1,"a,b"
2,bc
3,d
```

the table like this:

```
create table test(ind varchar(10),var varchar(20));
```

when I load this csv file:

```
load data infile 'test.csv' into table test
fields terminated by ',' ;
```

I change this 
the warning:

> row 1 was truncated: it contained more data than there were input columns
>   I try this:

```
load data infile 'test.csv' into table test
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
```

it doesn't work.

the common of "a,b" cause this error. but I don't know how to solve this question.

Comment: `it doesn't work` ... what happened with the second attempt using `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   yes, when I add optionally enclosed by ' " ',  the ind column only contain 1,the var column contain "a,b"       2,bc       3,d

Comment: I think `LOAD DATA` isn't seeing your line breaks for some reason.  I gave you a suggestion below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds like maybe `LOAD DATA` isn't properly picking up on your line breaks.  Try adding `LINES TERMINATED BY ...` to your call:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'         -- use '\n' if on Linux
(ind, var)
```

With the above call, MySQL should not view the comma inside the first quoted term `"a,b"` as being a field separator, but rather just part of the text of that column.

Comment: I had this issue when loading a CSV from my Windows machine to MySQL instance running on Linux.  Would have never thought about newlines, thanks...

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you so much, you have saved the day!